# message isolation in multi-tenant sqs consumers : share same queue for every tenant

Tags: amazon-sqs, multi-tenant

We want to use sqs for multiple tenants, where based on context producer adds tenant-id in message attribute. My consumers are running in their own premises, and would like to have message isolation among consumers of different tenant.

For ex : we have messages for tenant-A, tenant-B and consumers for these 2 tenants are running differently in their own premises. Then consumer(s) in tenant-A polls the queue, it should only return messages corresponding to tenant-A, it should never be able to see tenant-B message.

How can we achieve such isolation among consumers ? I see that we can pass attribute-name in receive-message request, but it doesn't filter messages on that.

Comment: By having multiple queues.

Comment: We have lot of tenants, so keeping separate queue for each tenant will be an operational overhead.. we want to achieve multi-tenancy with single sqs

Comment: This should help you solve your problem using filters https://event-driven-architecture.workshop.aws/4-sns/2-filtering/message-filtering.html

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this problem? 
I'm looking for a solution to the same scenario.